# Could not able to get the text body from articles while web scraping

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping news articles from the website https://www.scmp.com/
Though I can get the title or author names from each articles but I can't able to get the text body or main content of the articles. I followed two methods but both didn't work.

First method

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

lists = ['disable-popup-blocking']

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"

driver.get('https://www.scmp.com/news/asia/east-asia/article/3199400/japan-asean-hold-summit-tokyo-around-december-2023-japanese-official')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
text_res = bsObj.select('div[class="details__body body"]') 
    
text = ""
for item in text_res:
    if item.get_text() == "":
        continue
    text = text + item.get_text().strip() + "\n"
```

Second Method

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r"E:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe", options=options) #add your chrome path    

driver.get('https://www.scmp.com/news/asia/east-asia/article/3199400/japan-asean-hold-summit-tokyo-around-december-2023-japanese-official')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

a = driver.find_element_by_class_name("details__body body").text
print(a)
```

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons that you cannot obtain the text from the article on the South China Morning Post.

First when you open Chrome using `selenium` the URL for the article displays a GDRP notice.

*The GDRP has to be accepted via a button click.*

Second the page also displays a popup to set your news preferences.

*The news preference popup has to be `X` out.*

Third trying to extract the text using `selenium` will require some data cleaning.  I would recommend using `BeautifulSoup` to extract the clean article text from a script tag on the page.

Here is some rough code that clicks the GDRP button, `X` out the news preference popup and extract the article text.

This code can be refined to fit your needs.

```
import json
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

url_main = 'https://www.scmp.com/news/asia/east-asia/article/3199400/japan-asean-hold-summit-tokyo-around-december-2023-japanese-official'

driver.get(url_main)

driver.implicitly_wait(20)
element_has_bottom_message = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "has-bottom-messaging")))
if element_has_bottom_message:
    element_gdpr = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "gdpr-banner__accept")))
    if element_gdpr:
        gdrp_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='gdpr-banner__accept']")
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(gdrp_button).click(gdrp_button).perform()
        element_my_news_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "my-news-landing-popup__icon-close")))
        if element_my_news_popup:
            my_news_popup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='my-news-landing-popup__icon-close']")
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(my_news_popup).click(my_news_popup).perform()
            driver.implicitly_wait(20)
            raw_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
            json_dictionaries = raw_soup.find_all(name='script', attrs={'type': 'application/ld+json'})
            if len(json_dictionaries) != 0:
                for json_dictionary in json_dictionaries:
                    dictionary = json.loads("".join(json_dictionary.contents), strict=False)
                    article_bool = bool([value for (key, value) in dictionary.items() if key == 'articleBody'])
                    if article_bool:
                        for key, value in dictionary.items():
                            if key == 'articleBody':
                                print(value)


sleep(30)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The leaders of Japan and 10-member Asean on Saturday agreed to hold a summit in Tokyo 
in or around December next year to commemorate the 50th anniversary of their relationship, 
a Japanese official said. Japanese Prime Minister Fumio Kishida and his counterparts from 
the Association of Southeast Asian Nations also pledged to deepen their cooperative ties 
when they met in Phnom Penh, according to the official. Japan has been trying to boost 
relations with Asean at a time when some of its members are increasingly vigilant against 
China ’s assertive territorial claims in the East and South China seas . Why is Japan 
losing ground in Asean despite being a bigger investor than China? “Although concerns are 
growing over opaque and unfair development support, Japan will continue to back sustainable 
growth” of Southeast Asia , Kishida said at the outset of the meeting, which was open to 
the media, in a veiled reference to Beijing’s trade and economic practices. Leaders of 
several nations mentioned the importance of freedom of navigation and overflight in the 
South China Sea, and of the necessity of adhering to international law, the official said 
after the meeting. The agreement on the special summit in Tokyo came as the US and China 
have been intensifying their competition for influence in Southeast Asia. In November last 
year, China and Asean agreed to upgrade their ties to a “comprehensive strategic 
partnership” when the two sides held a special online summit commemorating the 30th 
anniversary of their dialogue, with Chinese President Xi Jinping making a rare appearance. 
China has stepped up efforts to expand its clout in the region as security tensions 
with the US escalate in nearby waters. After China’s move, the US in May declared with 
Asean that they had decided to elevate their relationship to a “comprehensive strategic 
partnership” as well. At the Asean-Japan gathering, Kishida also reiterated his support 
for the “Asean Outlook on the Indo-Pacific”, an initiative aimed at maintaining peace, 
freedom and prosperity in the region, the official said.
```